# Espresso pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAPS_LOCK) not working

Tags: kotlin, android-espresso, keyevent

This works:

```
  onView(withId(R.id.textView)).perform(replaceText("THI"))
            onView(withId(R.id.textView)).perform(
                doubleClick(),
                pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT)
            )
```

The below does not work as expected ( Getting a Capital 'S' char).

```
onView(withId(R.id.textView)).perform(

            pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAPS_LOCK),
            pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S),


            )
```

What am I doing wrong? Tested on a real device as well.